# How to stop nginx pass through from resolving upstream to IP

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to nginx reverse proxy configuration. We have a requirement to setup a proxy server to route requests to a remote server that requires IP whitelisting. Two way SSL is also in place.

We have been trying to it up hit a roadblock. Following is the configuration :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myserver.com;
   return 302 https://myserver.com;
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name myserver.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"; 
   ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/keys/my-net.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/keys/my-net.key;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $backend "https://remoteserver.com";
        proxy_pass $backend;

        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /home/ubuntu/myfile.pem;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
   }
}
```

The problem we are facing is that the proxy server is resolving the domain name to IP because of which SSLhandshake is failing. We need to stop this and hit the domain name because the certificate is on the domain name.

Error from error.log

2022/03/02 14:10:02 [error] 27012#27012: *8 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: <>, server: <>, request: "POST <> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https:<>", host: "<>"
2022/03/02 14:10:02 [alert] 27012#27012: *8 socket() failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol) while connecting to upstream, client: <>, server: <>, request: "POST /gateway/api/txb/v1/payments/transfer-payment HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[IPv6]:443/", host: "<>"

Already tried the solution here but no luck - [How to stop nginx from resolving upstream to ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580915/how-to-stop-nginx-from-resolving-upstream-to-ip)

Comment: *"We have been trying to it up hit a roadblock. "* - It is unclear to me what this is. Please describe the actual road block you are facing instead of just stating some unspecific "problem" and dumping the config.

Comment: *"The problem we are facing is ... SSLhandshake is failing."* - that is your problem. *"... the proxy server is resolving the domain name to IP because  ..."* - this is only your assumption why it is failing. Giving that you already have `proxy_ssl_server_name on` this assumption is wrong. It is failing for some other (unknown) reason. Please check with curl, `openssl s_client ..` or similar on the server that it is even possible to access `https://remoteserver.com` from the server.

Comment: Added the error message as well to the question. CURL from nginx to the target server is working as expected. Again, the reason for the assumption is from the error log showing IP in the URL instead of hostname. Thanks!

Comment: nginx must resolve the domain to the IP address in order to connect to the upstream. But that was not the point of the problem discussed in the question you've linked, instead it was nginx not using SNI to send the domain name inside the TLS handshake. This was addressed by using `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` - which is also shown in your config. So this looks like a different problem, unrelated to what you claim in the title. It would be interesting to see a packet capture of the failed connection from nginx compared to the successful from curl. Also look at logs in upstream for error infos.

Comment: Updated the latest error from error.log. No change in the config

Comment: To cite myself: *"It would be interesting to see a packet capture of the failed connection from nginx compared to the successful from curl."* - not given so far. *"Also look at logs in upstream for error infos."* - also not given, only nginx logs provided which only show that the upstream rejected the connection but not information from upstream why this might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to off  `proxy_pass_request_headers` after that set headers with `proxy_set_heder`  and listen ssl `listen 443 ssl;`

```sh
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myserver.com;
   return 302 https://myserver.com;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl; 
   server_name myserver.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"; 
   ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/keys/my-net.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/keys/my-net.key;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $backend "https://remoteserver.com";
        proxy_pass $backend;

        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /home/ubuntu/myfile.pem;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but seems like the same is happening : 

(IP removed due to security concerns)
[error] 11879#11879: *45 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: <<IP>>, server: myserver.com, request: "POST /gateway/api/txb/v1/payments/transfer-payment HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://115.112.85.180:443/gateway/api/txb/v1/payments/transfer-payment", host: "myserver.com"

Comment: and you need to listen ssl `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: It is, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @DeepakVn, I am facing similar issue, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: We ended up abandoning this approach and went ahead with a custom proxy server built on Python. If I remember correctly there was a need to enable IPV6 which we couldn't due to some unrelated stuff on our AWS VPC. Its been a while, I could be missing stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```